# Microsoft.Sharepoint.linq.dll file not found

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint

How can I get Microsoft.Sharepoint.linq.dll file if not there in the system?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll ?

you cant find Microsoft.Sharepoint.linq.dll on your local desktop.
for sharepoint development, you need to do this on sharepoint workstation.